# Python 3.2 - cookielib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have working 2.7 code, however there are no such thing as cookielib and urllib2 in 3.2? How can I make this code work on 3.2? In case someone is wondering - I'm on Windows.

*Example 2.7*

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : 'admin', 'pass' : '123'})

resp = opener.open('http://website/', login_data)
html = resp.read()

# I know that 3.2 is using print(), don't have to point that out.
print html
```

Comment: http://python3porting.com/stdlib.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html):

> Note The cookielib module has been renamed to http.cookiejar in Python
>   3.0. **The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0**.

Is that not an acceptable solution?  If not, why?

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned above cookielib has been renamed, use the following snippet for both python 2 and 3:

```
try:
    from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
except ImportError:
    from cookielib import CookieJar
```

Answer (score 19):

One line answer, that will solve your problem.

`import http.cookiejar as cookielib`

For python3.
No need to change the occurrence of cookielib in your code.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.2, urllib2 is renamed urllib.request, and cookielib is renamed http.cookiejar. So you rename it as urllib.request and http.cookijar