# Python PIP unsatisifed requirement cookielib3pp

Tags: python-3.x, pip, cookielib

I'd like to install cookielib for Python 3.5. However, I'm getting an unclear error message:

```
Tom@osx:~/mycode$ pip3 search cookielib
cookielib3     - 
Tom@osx:~/mycode$ pip3 install cookielib3
Collecting cookielib3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cookielib3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cookielib3
```

What is going on here?

Comment: take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405096/python-3-2-cookielib

Comment: How is this link supposed to answer my question?

Comment: In that subject is a complete answer to your question

Answer (score 3):

If you searched on `PyPi`, you probably saw: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cookielib3/0.0.0

It's a dummy package. In Python 3 there's no `cookielib` or `cookielib3`. According to [Python 3.2 - cookielib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405096/python-3-2-cookielib) you should use `http.cookiejar` instead.