# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookielib'

Tags: python, urllib2, cookielib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookielib' and 'urllib2'

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'yourusername'

password = 'yourpassword'

ck = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

loginn = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})

opener.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', login_data)

resp = opener.open('http://www.facebook.com/')

resp.read()

print(resp)
```

Now whenever I try to run python I get ImportError: no module named cookielib and urllib2. What happened? Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to run Python2 code in a Python3 environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.2 - cookielib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405096/python-3-2-cookielib)

Answer (score 3):

These two libraries are renamed / changed in python 3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857677/python-3-2-wont-import-cookielib/44894126) should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Check first which python version you are using to execute code. To check python version use check this in terminal:

```
C:\Users\real>python --version
Python 3.9.10
```

If you are working with python3.X, then library `urllib2`, `cookielib` are not available for any version `3.x`.
I found this [resources](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-4302-2416-7/1.pdf) if you wand to migrate from `python2.x` to `python3.x`
The `cookielib` module has been renamed to `http.cookiejar` in Python 3.0. Docs for [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html).

```
try:
    import cookielib
except:
    import http.cookiejar
    cookielib = http.cookiejar
```

Also `urllib2` module is changed to `urllib3` module in python3.X. Docs for [urrlib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)